# Is this a correct way to block kafkastreams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, spring-kafka

My job is to grab data from remote db and join them into a kafka stream(enrichment). What I want to do now is periodically polling remote db into local memory. I think when this polling operation happens, kafka stream should be temporarily stopped. My current thought is to have something like this:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaStreams streams;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * * * *")  // this method is scheduled to run every 15 minutes
public synchronized void process() {
    streams.close();
    processPolling();
    streams.start();
}
```

When the method starts to run, the streams should be stopped processing, and then the polling job finished to run, the stream should restart to process.

Is this a good practice? any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Kafka does not sound like the right tool for your requirement. If you need to stop and restart a streaming process, then it's just a batch job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to do this would be to stream the remote DB into Kafka topic(s), and use these natively in your Streams job. 
You can use the [JDBC Connector](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html#quickstart), or there are various CDC options depending on what your source database is.

Starting and stopping streams makes it a batch process, with the associated considerations and complications that stream processing avoids by design.

Comment: I need to query the remote DB data based on one field of record in stream, so I'd like to store them as a hashmap like structure to boost query performance. If make remote DB data a stream, how should I do the query? Thanks.

Comment: This is a separate question on efficient design & use of Kafka Streams. There's StackOverflow, there's also a Confluent Platform mailing list and Slack group for assistance : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/confluent-platform  / https://slackpass.io/confluentcommunity